# REACT my custom crosshair does not activate onclick functions

Tags: reactjs

I created a custom crosshair using react and I can't seem to get it click on certain elements such as a button it won't let me click the button but If I removed the custom crosshair the button onclick will let me click and it will run the function associated with the button I tried creating a zIndex css to have the cursor overlapped the other crosshair but that did not work any suggestion to make it where I can click other elements and the function can run? written via codepen

```js
const { useRef } = React

const Main = props => {
  const cursor = {
    cursor: "crosshair",
    width: "20PX",
    height: "20PX",
    position: "fixed",
  };
  
  const borders = {
    width: "800px",
    height: "500px",
    backgroud: "#ccc",
    border: "4px solid #333"
  }
  
  const textInput = useRef()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) =>{
      textInput.current.style.top =   event.clientY  + 'px' 
      textInput.current.style.bottom =  event.clientX  + 'px'
      textInput.current.style.left = event.clientX + 'px' 
      textInput.current.style.right = event.clientY  + 'px' 
    })
    console.log("dsadas")
  });
  
  return (<div  style={borders} >
    <div ref={textInput} style={cursor}>
    </div>   <button >dsa2222ads</button></div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main  />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Please add punctuation to your question. It is *really* hard to read write now when it is not clear where one sentence ends and the next one starts.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question, while ingenious, cannot be fixed as-is, because of 2 main reasons:

1. The `cursor` element is receiving all click events instead of what's beneath it;
2. As pointed out in comments, my initial suggestion (to use `pointer-events: none;` styling on the `cursor` element) does make the button work properly, but the `cursor: crosshair;` style stops working because the element gets ignored when it comes to ALL pointer aspects, not only events.

The following alternative relies purely on CSS, more specifically on the `*` selector to assign the `cursor: crosshair;` style to all elements at any depth inside the containing element (and also place it on the `borders` element). The markup gets lighter since we don't need the `cursor` element any more and no more code to move it around the page. Also no more document-level event listeners.

```css
.borders {
  cursor: crosshair;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 4px solid #333;
}

.borders * {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<div class="borders">
  <button onClick="alert('Ok!')">Button</button>
</div>
```

Now, should you need a different cursor on just some internal elements, you can easily achieve that using selector specificity to target that element and put `cursor: auto;` or whatever you need on it. If you want to restore the crosshair on that element's children, just re-apply the `*` selector, and so on. So you have complete and granular control over the cursor all with CSS. If a code sample for this scenario is needed, let me know in the comments. Thank you!

Comment: this works functionality wise but the cursor: crosshair property dissapears now